# A cylindrical reservoir

Tags: calculus, derivatives

A reservoir has the shape of a vertical cylinder with height $3m$ and radius $4m$ and it is filled with water.

i) Let x be the height in meters measured from the bottom of the reservoir. The weight in Newtons of a thin layer of water between $x$ and $x+\Delta x$ is approximately $P(x)\Delta x$. What is $P(x)$?

ii) The work in Joules required to pump the thin water layer to 3 meters above the reservoir is approximately $w(x)\Delta x$. What is $w(x)$

iii) Using previous results, find, in Joules, the amount of work required to pump all the water 3 meters above the reservoir.

I am unable to solve part (i), so if someone could shed a little light on this question, I may be able to solve the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean $3$ m. and $4$ m.

The thin layer of water has volume $\pi r^2 h = \pi (4)^2\Delta x$. Let $\rho$ be the density of water, and thus the weight is $16\pi\rho\Delta x$. Go look up the density of water, and you have your answer.

Comment: I think you missed 'g' i.e. acceleration due to gravity..

Comment: @Mathematics, I was considering density to be "weight per volume", not "mass per volume", (that being how I deal with it all the time) but your point is well-taken. Ananya should take care to get weight, not mass.